# Modify code to play and download mp3 at the same time, not download mp3 then play it in Swift/SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have created this code to play/stop/rewind tracks that will be downloaded at the device and stored in cache. The only problem is that it starts playing only when the track will be fully downloaded. Before that the app freezes completely. It's not a problem with small mp3, but what if it will be 30 minutes audio? I need to modify this code to start audio playing immediately and download the track in the background. Seek help here because there is no guides how to do it with AVAudioPlayer. Thanks.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import AVFAudio

final class AudioManager: ObservableObject {
    
    // static let shared = AudioManager()
    
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    @Published private(set) var isDownloading = false
    @Published private(set) var isPlaying: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print(isPlaying, "isPlaying")
        }
    }
    @Published private(set) var isLooping: Bool = false
    
    @MainActor func startPlayer(track: String) async {
        
        guard let fileURL = URL(string: track) else { return  }
        
        do {
            
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            
            
            let songName = fileURL.lastPathComponent
            var soundData: Data
            let tracksFolderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!.appendingPathComponent("tracks")
            let trackUrl = tracksFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent(songName)
            
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: trackUrl.path) {
                // Load local data if it exists
                print("Loading data from \(trackUrl)")
                soundData = try Data(contentsOf: trackUrl)
            } else {
                
                //… otherwise load from network
                isDownloading = true
                print("Downloading data from \(fileURL)")
                (soundData, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: fileURL)
                
                //… then save to disk
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: tracksFolderUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
                print("Saving data to \(trackUrl)")
                try soundData.write(to: trackUrl)
                isDownloading = false
            }
            
            self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
            isPlaying = true
        }
        catch {
            
            print(error)
            
        }
    }
    
    func playPause() {
        
        guard let player = player else {
            print("Audio player not found")
            return
        }
        
        if player.isPlaying {
            player.pause()
            isPlaying = false

        } else {
            player.play()
            isPlaying = true

        }
        
    }
    
    func stop() {
        guard let player = player else {
            print("Audio player not found")
            return
        }
        
        if player.isPlaying {
            player.stop()
            isPlaying = false
        }
        
    }
    
    func toggleLoop() {
        guard let player = player else { return }
        
        player.numberOfLoops = player.numberOfLoops == 0 ? -1 : 0
        isLooping = player.numberOfLoops != 0
        print("isLooping", isLooping)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will suspend while

```
(soundData, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: fileURL)
```

is downloading data.

To stream files initialise the `AVPlayer` with the URL:

```
AVPlayer(url: url)
```

If you also want to download the data to save locally you can do that separately.

---

To get the duration of the track:

```
player.currentItem?.duration
```

to get the current playback position:

```
player.currentTime()
```

Apple's documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer).

Comment: I can't use it because I won't be able to pass to slider information about track length  etc.

Comment: Please read the `AVPlayer` documentation, this information is available there. I added some more to my answer